# Exposing ViewModel with RequireJS and KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, amd

If I have a function that's part of an object("viewModel") how can I expose this via requirejs.

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: function() { viewModel.addFlight(id) } ">Add Flight</a>
```

I've read this documentation but doesn't seem to address this unless I'm missing something.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/amd-loading.html

```
define(function () {

    var viewModel = {
       flights: ko.observableArray([]),
       addFlight: function (id) {
       }
    }

  return viewModel;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
define(function () {
    var viewModel = {
       this.flights = ko.observableArray([]),
       this.addFlight = function (id) {
       }
    }

  return viewModel;
});
```